# My Python for loop is giving the result None

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, append

In code below, this loop is supposed to take a tuple, say (1,2,3), a key from a dictionary, turn it into a list, [1,2,3], stick a 1 on the end, [1,2,3,1] and, for each key, add this new list to a longer list called new_training_data.

This is what I have written:

```
my_training_data={
    (1,2,3,4):[1,0,0],
    (1.2,1.8,3.2,3.8):[1,0,0],
    (1.1,1.9,3.1,3.9):[1,0,0],
    (4,3,2,1):[0,1,0],
    (3.8,3,2,1.8,1.2):[0,1,0],
    (3.9,3.1,1.9,1.1):[0,1,0]
}
def part_1(my_training_data):
   for key in sorted(my_training_data):
       new_training_data=[]
       new_training_data=new_training_data.append(list(key).extend([1]))
   return new_training_data
```

And when I type

```
print part_1(my_training_data)
```

I get the result `None`.

Please help! I've been struggling with this for a while.

PS. I am writing this in IPython, having downloaded Anaconda for 64 bit Windows, version 2.7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are reinitializing `new_training_data` in every run of the for loop, move it out. Also, the result of `list(key).extend([1])` is None (as in None is returned), so the list will contain only a single None in the final iteration.

So, do the following:

```
def part_1(my_training_data):
   new_training_data=[]
   for key in sorted(my_training_data):
       new_training_data.append(list(key) + [1])
   return new_training_data
```

***Edit***: Complete run

```
>>> my_training_data={
...     (1,2,3,4):[1,0,0],
...     (1.2,1.8,3.2,3.8):[1,0,0],
...     (1.1,1.9,3.1,3.9):[1,0,0],
...     (4,3,2,1):[0,1,0],
...     (3.8,3,2,1.8,1.2):[0,1,0],
...     (3.9,3.1,1.9,1.1):[0,1,0]
... }
>>> def part_1(my_training_data):
...    new_training_data=[]
...    for key in sorted(my_training_data):
...        new_training_data.append(list(key) + [1])
...    return new_training_data
... 
>>> part_1(my_training_data)
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 1], [1.1, 1.9, 3.1, 3.9, 1], [1.2, 1.8, 3.2, 3.8, 1], [3.8, 3, 2, 1.8, 1.2, 1], [3.9, 3.1, 1.9, 1.1, 1], [4, 3, 2, 1, 1]]
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! I have tried taking the new_training_data=[] out of the for loop (ie. as you've done here) but then for some reason, on printing, I get an error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'. Any idea why this is happening? I don't see how the object type has changed!

Comment: @eibb95 Note the change he made with `extend` as well, that is causing you trouble still.

Comment: Ah, never mind, I somehow copied out your code wrong - it works, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

if I understood correctly your questions, this is what you are apparently looking for:

```
def part_1(my_training_data):
    new_training_data = []
    for key in sorted(my_training_data):
        new_training_data.append(list(key)+[1])
    return new_training_data
```

Comment: Can you give an explanation of what was wrong in the question/why this works?

Comment: Every time the loop ran, new_training_data variable was declared as an empty list. The variable in which you want to append to has to be outside the loop.